# Find out which program is asking for privilege escalation?

Tags: pam

I have a finger print reader on my laptop, and I configured PAM with fprintd,

sometimes when it lights up, I want to find out which program is asking for a privilege escalation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [parm_warn module](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_warn.html) will log the service (and the terminal, user, remote user and remote host) to syslog. This will tell you the service (and assuming syslog is called with that option) the pid in question.

As this should log to the AUTHPRIV syslog facility, usually going to the root readable-only file /var/log/secure, this may not be as accessible as you'd like. This would be a good starting point to coding a custom module to give you better notification.

There are also web search hits for individual's pam_log modules that allow logging more arbitrary text and fields.